# Rspec test on response should be successful fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm running this test on rspec...

```
it 'get email is successful' do
  get :email
  response.should be_success
  response.should render_template('email')
```

end

Where the controller code looks like this..

```
def email
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js 
  end
end
```

On my terminal I'm returning with....

```
3) PostsController checking to see if response for post email is successful
 Failure/Error: response.should be_success
   expected success? to return true, got false
 # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:116:in `block (3 levels) in <top    
(required)>'
```

What am I missing here to make the test work? It has to be something obvious. My view file is titled `email.js.erb`. This action is meant for an AJAX call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
xhr :get, :email
```

your request seems not to take into account the expected response type. In Rspec, this is the way to do it if you want to simulate AJAX (XHR) requests.

Answer (score 3):

Your controller is structured to return anything only for JS requests and you are requesting HTML response in your tests. You should have

`get :email.js`

in your spec.

Comment: Both solutions return with undefined method js.